# Imageview not displaying captured image

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the image to capture and display in the `ImageView` on Android Studio, but it just captures and doesnt display the image.

**CODE:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button click;
    private static final int camRequest = 1;
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        click.setOnClickListener(delListener);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener delListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view){
            try {
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, camRequest);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                Log.e("", "errpr");

            }

        }};

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //super.onActivityResult( requestCode,  resultCode,  data);
        if (resultCode == camRequest) {
            Bitmap bit2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bit2);
        }

    }
```

I think I have been doing everything right and in the `Manifest` file I have added the permission for the camera already, so that is not an issue.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: If you are testing in post lollipop user needs to grant `runtime permission`

Answer (score 1):

The error is in :

`if (resultCode == camRequest)`

`resultCode` is used by the `Activity` to show if the result is either `OK` or `ERROR`.

Replace it with:

`if (requestCode == camRequest && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)`

Answer (score 1):

Result code should not be compared there, correct way :

```
...
// check if request code is camRequest
if(requestCode == camRequest){  
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        // If result is okay...do something
    } else {
        // there was a failure.
    }
}
```

Comment: DId @M.Waqas Pervez said something else?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know he has answered while I was answering, I didn't know that he has answered, it got updated later.